# mysql error 1064 when creating table. What can I check for?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting an ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 21, which is VIN_Number in Vehicle table. Entity Inventory gets built without a problem, VIN_Number is of type varchar(17) for all occurrences. I believe the tables are being built in the correct order. I can't find any spelling or punctuation errors. I'm out of ideas of things I should checked. What is it that I'm missing?

Note: I getting an error for Invoice as well, but I know that it can't be created until Vehicle gets created.

```
ALTER TABLE Vehicle DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_Veh_Vehicle_TypeID;
ALTER TABLE Inventory DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_Inv_Vehicle_TypeID;
ALTER TABLE Invoice DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_Customer_ID;
ALTER TABLE Invoice DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_Sales_Person_ID;
ALTER TABLE Invoice DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_VIN_Number;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Vehicle, VehicleType,
    Invoice, Customer, SalesPerson, Inventory;


CREATE TABLE VehicleType (
  Vehicle_TypeID int NOT NULL,
  Veh_Make varchar(15),
  Veh_Model varchar(15),
  Veh_Year int,
  PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle_TypeID) 
) Engine=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE Vehicle (
  VIN_Number varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  Vehicle_TypeID int NOT NULL,
  Condition varchar(10),
  Color varchar(8),
  PRIMARY KEY (VIN_Number),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Veh_Vehicle_TypeID FOREIGN KEY(Vehicle_TypeID)
    REFERENCES VehicleType(Vehicle_TypeID)
) Engine=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE Inventory (
  Stock_ID int NOT NULL,
  Vehicle_TypeID int NOT NULL,
  Quantity int,
  PRIMARY KEY (Stock_ID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Inv_Vehicle_TypeID FOREIGN KEY (Vehicle_TypeID)
    REFERENCES VehicleType(Vehicle_TypeID)
) Engine=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE Customer (
  Customer_ID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  Cus_LastName varchar(15),
  Cus_FirstName varchar(15),
  Cus_Street varchar(20),
  Cus_City varchar(15),
  Cus_Zip varchar(5),
  Cus_Phone varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID)
) Engine=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE SalesPerson (
  Sales_Person_ID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  Sal_LastName varchar(15),
  Sal_FirstName varchar(15),
  Sal_Street varchar(15),
  Sal_City varchar(15),
  Sal_Zip varchar(5),
  Sal_Phone varchar(10),
  Sal_Years_Worked int,
  Sal_Commission_Rate float(4),
  PRIMARY KEY (Sales_Person_ID)
) Engine=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE Invoice (
  Invoice_ID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  Customer_ID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  Sales_Person_ID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  VIN_Number varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  Price float(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (Invoice_ID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Customer_ID FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID)
    REFERENCES Customer(Customer_ID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Sales_Person_ID FOREIGN KEY (Sales_Person_ID)
    REFERENCES SalesPerson(Sales_Person_ID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_VIN_Number FOREIGN KEY (VIN_Number)
    REFERENCES Vehicle(VIN_Number)
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

Comment: What is the **exact, complete** error message you're getting?

Comment: Your column lengths are *extremely* stingy. Why are you restricting things so ridiculously tight? Fifteen characters for a last name is completely inadequate. Every single one of these is likely to come back to bite you later because they're too short. Unless you have a really solid reason to deviate, use the default of 255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of the Vehicle table you have a column named `condition` which is a reserved keyword in MySQL ([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html)). Either use another name for the column or enclose it in backticks like this: `` `condition` ``

Using keywords (reserved or not) for object names is generally something you want to avoid.

Comment: Even better, don't use reserved keywords for table or column names.

Comment: @jpw I've just started studying SQL in school and had no idea that there were so many reserved words. Thanks.

Comment: @WP0987 Yeah, in my experience schools often don't mention specifics that relate to any specific database. Some of the keywords come from the standard and some are product specific and thus varies.